# Convert "1.79769313486232E+308" to double without OverflowException?

Tags: c#, .net, double

I have this string "1.79769313486232E+308" and am trying to convert it to a .NET numeric value (double?) but am getting the below exception.  I am using `Convert.ToDouble()`.  What is the proper way to do this conversion?

> OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Double

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the fact that `Double.MaxValue` was converted to a string, and when the string is output, not all the digits are output, instead it is rounded. Parsing this value overflows the double.

Using `Double.TryParse` and subsequently checking equality on the string "1.79769313486232E+308" in case of failure and substituting `Double.MaxValue` should be a quick workaround, if you need to keep the string the way it is.

EDIT: Of course, if you don't need to keep the string the way it is, use the [Round Trip format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#RFormatString) to produce the string in the first place, as [Jon describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/767011/58391).

Answer (score 26):

Unfortunately this value is greater than `double.MaxValue`, hence the exception.

As codekaizen suggests, you could hard-code a test for the string. A better (IMO) alternative if you're the one *producing* the string in the first place is to use the "r" format specifier. Then the string you produce will be "1.7976931348623157E+308" instead, which then parses correctly:

```
string s = double.MaxValue.ToString("r");
double d = double.Parse(s); // No exception
```

Obviously that's no help if you don't have control over the data - but then you should understand you're likely to be losing data already in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You may try `double.Parse()` or `double.TryParse()` rather than `Convert.ToDouble()`, but I'm not certain you'll get better results. Incidentally, the string that you provide is equal to `double.MaxValue`, which is (of course) the maximum value that can be contained in a double, so that's likely where your error is coming from. Floating-point numeric types are finicky, so I would assume that some sort of rounding is taking place and pushing it outside the bounds of the type.

You could also try the `decimal` data type. You may have better luck there.

Comment: Or just use double.MaxValue directly?  Or do a string test for that particular string and substitute double.MaxValue, since it's obviously a special case.

Comment: Decimal won't work at all. Decimal.MaxValue < Double.MaxValue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with.  Thanks Jon Skeet and codekaizen.

```
private double convertToDouble(string str)
{
    double dbl;

    if (double.TryParse(str, out dbl))
        return dbl;

    if (str == "1.79769313486232E+308")
        return double.MaxValue;

    return double.MinValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrates the issue and a solution:

```
var s = double.MaxValue.ToString();
double d;
if (!double.TryParse(s, out d)) {
    d = s.Equals(double.MaxValue) ? double.MaxValue : double.MinValue;
}
```

Comment: This is WRONG solution! If TryParse returns `false`, then the `result` value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here a more generic implementation which representing different formatting and cultures and is more tolerant:

```
#region MatchDoubleMinMaxValuesRegex
/// <summary>
/// This regex matches strings which represents either a <see cref="double.MinValue"/> or a <see cref="double.MaxValue"/>.
/// If it is a <see cref="double.MinValue"/> then the group "isNegative" will be matched as <see cref="Group.Success"/>.
/// </summary>
private static readonly Regex MatchDoubleMinMaxValuesRegex = new Regex(
    @"
        ^
        (?>(?<isNegative>-)|\+?)
        1
        (?>[,.]?)
        79769313486232
        (?>
            [eE]\+308|
            0{294}(?>[,.]|$)
        )
    ",
    RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace
);
#endregion

/// <summary>
/// Converts the string representation of a number in a specified culture-specific format to its double-precision floating-point number equivalent.
/// <para>This implementation is more tolerant compared to the native double.Parse implementation:
/// strings representing <see cref="double.MinValue"/> and <see cref="double.MaxValue"/> can be parsed without <see cref="OverflowException"/>.</para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">A string that contains a number to convert.</param>
/// <param name="cultureInfo">For some type conversions optional culture information that shall be used to parse the value.
/// If not specified, then the Current Culture will be used.</param>
/// <param name="numberStyles">For some type conversions optional number style configuration that shall be used to parse the value.
/// If not specified, then the default will be used.</param>
/// <returns>A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to the numeric value or symbol specified in <paramref name="s"/>.</returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException"><paramref name="s"/> is <c>null</c>.</exception>
/// <exception cref="FormatException"><paramref name="s"/> does not represent a number in a valid format.</exception>
/// <exception cref="OverflowException"><paramref name="s"/> represents a number that is less than <see cref="double.MinValue"/> or greater than <see cref="double.MaxValue"/>.</exception>
public static double ParseDoubleEx(string s, CultureInfo cultureInfo = null, NumberStyles? numberStyles = null)
{
    // Try parse
    double tempValue;
    bool parseSuccess = (numberStyles != null)
        ? double.TryParse(s, numberStyles.Value, cultureInfo, out tempValue)
        : double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, cultureInfo, out tempValue);

    // If parsing failed, check for Min or Max Value (by pattern)
    if (parseSuccess == false)
    {
        Match match = MatchDoubleMinMaxValuesRegex.Match(s);
        if (match.Success == true)
            tempValue = (match.Groups["isNegative"].Success == false)
                ? double.MaxValue
                : double.MinValue;
        else
            throw new OverflowException("A double-precision floating-point number that is equivalent to the numeric value or symbol specified in s.");
    }

    return tempValue;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I get the same number at times. Here's how I addressed it.

var str = "1.79769313486232E+308";
var dbl = double.Parse(str.Replace("E+", ""));

Comment: Ooh, your answer will silently incorrectly parse the intended value of the string.  Just removing the Exponentiation symbol will produce a completely different number without raising an error.  The exception that the OP is getting is for good reason - the number is too large for a .NET double data type.

Answer (score -2):

That number is too big for a double, as the exception says. You are going to have to find a large number library to handle that for you, as there is nothing that I know of in the .Net library that handles very large numbers.